# How to create student mark sheet like Turm in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to show a student mark sheet like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
                    FIRST TURM   | SECOND TURM|
---------------------------------------------------------
 S_ID | SUB_NAME | OutOF | Marks | OutOF | Marks 
---------------------------------------------------------
  101    ENGLISH      100     90     100 90
  101    HISTORY      100     80     100 80
  101    MATHS        140     80     140 80
  101    SANSKRIT     100     75     100 75
  102    ENGLISH      100     80     100 80 
  102    HISTORY      100     80     100 80 
  102    MATHS        140     80     140 80  
  102    SANSKRIT     100     80     100 80
```

I use pivot keyword for this i get this output

```
create table #t 
(
    S_ID int, SUB_NAME varchar(10), OutOF int, Marks int, Turm int
)

insert into #t (S_ID,SUB_NAME,turm,OutOF ,Marks)VALUES(101,&#39;MATHS&#39;,1,140,80)
insert into #t (S_ID,SUB_NAME,turm,OutOF ,Marks)VALUES(101,&#39;ENGLISH&#39;,1,100,90)
insert into #t (S_ID,SUB_NAME,turm,OutOF ,Marks)VALUES(101,&#39;SANSKRIT&#39;,1,100,75)
insert into #t (S_ID,SUB_NAME,turm,OutOF ,Marks)VALUES(101,&#39;HISTORY&#39;,1,100,80)
insert into #t (S_ID,SUB_NAME,turm,OutOF ,Marks)VALUES(102,&#39;MATHS&#39;,1,140,80)
insert into #t (S_ID,SUB_NAME,turm,OutOF ,Marks)VALUES(102,&#39;ENGLISH&#39;,1,140,80)
insert into #t (S_ID,SUB_NAME,turm,OutOF ,Marks)VALUES(102,&#39;SANSKRIT&#39;,1,140,80)
insert into #t (S_ID,SUB_NAME,turm,OutOF ,Marks)VALUES(102,&#39;HISTORY&#39;,1,140,80)

insert into #t (S_ID,SUB_NAME,turm,OutOF ,Marks)VALUES(101,&#39;MATHS&#39;,2,140,80)
insert into #t (S_ID,SUB_NAME,turm,OutOF ,Marks)VALUES(101,&#39;ENGLISH&#39;,2,100,90)
insert into #t (S_ID,SUB_NAME,turm,OutOF ,Marks)VALUES(101,&#39;SANSKRIT&#39;,2,100,75)
insert into #t (S_ID,SUB_NAME,turm,OutOF ,Marks)VALUES(101,&#39;HISTORY&#39;,2,100,80)
insert into #t (S_ID,SUB_NAME,turm,OutOF ,Marks)VALUES(102,&#39;MATHS&#39;,2,140,80)
insert into #t (S_ID,SUB_NAME,turm,OutOF ,Marks)VALUES(102,&#39;ENGLISH&#39;,2,140,80)
insert into #t (S_ID,SUB_NAME,turm,OutOF ,Marks)VALUES(102,&#39;SANSKRIT&#39;,2,140,80)
insert into #t (S_ID,SUB_NAME,turm,OutOF ,Marks)VALUES(102,&#39;HISTORY&#39;,2,140,80)

select * 
from 
    (SELECT 
        S_ID, SUB_NAME,
        CASE WHEN turm = 1 THEN &#39;FIRST TURM&#39; ELSE &#39;SECOND TURM&#39; END AS turm,
        OutOF, Marks 
     FROM #t) S
PIVOT 
( 
   MAX(Marks) FOR [turm] IN ([FIRST TURM], [SECOND TURM])) S

drop  table  #t
```

Output:

```
S_ID | SUB_NAME | OutOF |FIRST  TURM |SECOND TURM 
--------------------------------------------------
101 ENGLISH  100      90              90
101 HISTORY  100      80              80
101 MATHS    140      80              80
101 SANSKRIT 100      75              75
102 ENGLISH  140      80              80
102 HISTORY  140      80              80
102 MATHS    140      80              80
102 SANSKRIT 140      80              80
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be solved like this :

```
select S_ID,SUB_NAME,OutOF, 
Max(case when turm =1 then marks else 0 end) as 'First Turm',
Max(case when turm =2 then marks else 0 end) as 'Second Turm'
from t group by S_ID,SUB_NAME,OutOF
```

Comment: sir i have multiple term exam, i give first view in my question if you have any solution please give me